# Make iframe fit the entire page on a Droid phone

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following code that sizes the iframe perfectly on tablets,computers, etc. and iphones. It creates an iframe approximately half the size of the entire screen on a droid phone. It fits the entire screen upon a refresh. How could I approach to fix this so that the iframe fits the entire page on a droid phone on first load?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<iframe src="/index2.php" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Try to use chrome developer tools and attach your phone to the computer so you can inspect element directly on your phone to see what is happening.

Comment: Mike, That works. Please answer so I could award you the point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser to fill the whole page with the main document. Use this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```